# ClassNotFoundException org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap when using POI Library

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I want to add "xlsx" support for my J2EE Web application. 
you can see the referenced library content:
[image]

At first, it was showing  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject . After I added xmlbeans-3.0.0.jar, the excpetion is now org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap.

Then I have also added commons-collections4-4.1.jar into the build path. 
However, the problem persists.

Anyone can help!?

Comment: As you probably already know, ListValuedMap was first introduced in Apache Commons 4.1.  But commons-collections-4.4.1.jar should be fine.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Q: Have you tried rebuilding your project and redeplying your .war?   2)  Q: Have you checked that commons-collections-4.4.1.jar is actually deployed where you expect it (for example, in your .war's WEB-INF/lib directory)?

Comment: yes, I have rebuild the project and output a war file for testing but still not work.

Comment: Does ... the ... war ... have ... commons-collections-4.4.1.jar in WEB-INF/lib???

Comment: oh, interestingly ... no.. I have added the jar by Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Library > Add External JARs. but no jar included in war? BTW, I have rebuilded and run locally, still not working

Comment: sorry, for stupid problem, I just copy and paste the JARs to WEB-INF.lib